# Cannot run WOInstaller.jar and thus cannot create frameworks in WOLips

Tags: java, eclipse, webobjects

I am installing WOLips. I have installed the plugins in Eclipse and everything seems fine (except Goodies won't install). I have tried to run WOInstaller.jar but I get a "connection time out" error:

$ sudo java -jar WOInstaller.jar 5.4.3 $HOME/workspace/WebObjects543/Versions/WebObjects543. 
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

This is the build recommended for my version of Eclipse on Debian. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. It was a proxy problem. Using java -Dhttp.proxyHost=10.0.0.0 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -jar etc. it works!